# Python, Pandas: Insert specific value into empty cells (by column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Good evening,

is it possible to simply replace all empty cells - empty string, not nan - in a specific column with a given string or integer?

Let's say...

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| john doe | 27 |
| jane doe | 29 |
| marianne mustermann |  |
| max mustermann | 23 |
| jean dupont |  |

to...

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| john doe | 27 |
| jane doe | 29 |
| marianne mustermann | 0 |
| max mustermann | 23 |
| jean dupont | 0 |

Thank you for all your help and have great day!

Comment: Can you post an initialized dataframe that we can use to test and validate answers?

Comment: `df.age.replace('', "0")`

Comment: @j__carlson - df.age looks like a float to me.

Comment: @tdelaney - OP specified 'empty string' .

Comment: @j__carlson - right, but didn't actually show us the dtype. We don't know what the data really is. Note the request: "with a given string or integer"

Comment: @tdelaney- If so `df.age.astype(str).replace('', "0")`.

Comment: @j__carlson - I don't know. finethen won't give us the information so its just a guess. I think we close looking for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a NaN to demonstrate this works:

```
df

    name                age
0   john doe            27.0
1   jane doe            29.0
2   marianne mustermann 
3   max mustermann      23.0
4   jean dupont 
5   final               NaN

df['age'] = df['age'].replace('',0)
df

    name                age
0   john doe            27.0
1   jane doe            29.0
2   marianne mustermann 0.0
3   max mustermann      23.0
4   jean dupont         0.0
5   final               NaN

df.dropna()

    name                age
0   john doe            27.0
1   jane doe            29.0
2   marianne mustermann 0.0
3   max mustermann      23.0
4   jean dupont         0.0
```